# Which mac os version is working pretty good with Valgrind?

Tags: valgrind, macos-mojave

I'm asking that because I was using Bigsur 2 days ago and no available version is currently working with Bigsur, so I downgraded my os to El capitan and I tested all options but no one is working. Today I am using Mojave 10.14.6 and still no version available.. Do you know a mac os version is working fine with valgrind please ? Thank's !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MacOS 10.13 is the last supported in the official git repo.

You should be able to get 10.14 to work with an unofficial clone (look for Louis Brunner on GitHub, there should be a brew recipe as well).

The poor state of affairs is all down to lack of resources. The Valgrind dev team has a fairly high bar to become a submitter. No-one is actively working on macOS. If people want Valgrind on macOS then we (the Valgrind dev team) need someone to step up and make a long term commitment to working on it.

Finally, there is also a significant possibility that macOS will be removed entirely from the official Valgrind repo. This was discussed as a possibility for 3.19. The subject hasn’t been raised for the next release (3.20 due out next month, October 2022).